# Is resolved-error.com associated in any way with SO?

Tags: support, copycat-sites

As stated in the title, while googling I stumbled upon resolved-error.com (link syntax not working for some reason) - the title bar says *forbidden - stack exchange* with an SO icon, it says something about my (wrong) IP being forbidden, a big stack exchange icon, and a `mailto` link to `team@stackexchange.com`. The source after a quick scan does not seem particularly suspicious but this was a high up search hit at `reloved-error.com/questions/something-close-to-my-search`.

I do not really think it is associated, but I thought I would ask, and if not, does something need to be done about the site.

Comment: Also see [copycat-sites] for more information.

Comment: @HansPassant the site does not seem like the standard run of the mill copy cat site, does it though? I was hoping  someone might guess what the site would intend to do with traffic, but in any case, just leave it is the answer?

Comment: @connectyourcharger see comment above.

Comment: Yes, I definitely understand, but I still think it's just generally related as the larger topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not.  Using an internet based WhoIS tool, this domain was registered on October 10 this year by a Russian registrar and has Russian contact information.

Comment: I wonder how an agency/malicious someone/teenage hacker for fun could use such a site.

Comment: @kabanus having questions/answers on a website is enough to drive quite a bit of traffic to it, traffic which could then be leveraged to make $$. SO's data is public, and therefore an easy source of Q/A pairs to put on your site to drive traffic.

Comment: @KevinB I do not doubt that, but the site is just a big "denied" sign post. There is no content (copied or not). These could be a baiting process if you attach this concept with some kind of account creation, but there was nothing obvious (to me) currently on the site.Perhaps if decide to mail the address things can advance, though that seems kind of a long run scam for the usual click bait sites.